# An array of a certain size in z3

Tags: python, arrays, z3, smt, formal-verification

I'm using the z3py library for a program verification project, and would like to encode accesses to arrays in z3. Is there a simple way to make the Array z3type have a certain size, say, 112 entries for instance?
I'm thinking of something like: A = Array('A', IntSort(), size)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array with 112 integer elements, you should declare it as

```
A = IntVector('A', 112)
```